# Haskell: How do I use the Maybe type in recursive functions?

Tags: haskell, recursion, types

Suppose I want to construct a function that turns a string of letters into a list of chars.

An example would be we input abc and it would output `[a,b,c]`

I constructed the function:

```
tester:: String-> [Char]
tester []= []
tester (x:xs)= case x of
    a -> a: (tester  xs)
    b -> b: (tester  xs)
    c -> c: (tester  xs)
    otherwise -> [n,o]
```

Haskell gives the errors that `n` and `o` aren't in scope.
but `n` and `o` are both Chars aern't they? Hence `[n,o]` is a `[Char]`, fitting the output type. What is the problem?

I remember reading somewhere that string is just a list of `Char`s, so is `String` the same as `[Char]`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Maybe`. And no. `tester` is just a sequence of characters _in your code_, yet it isn't a `String`. You have to use `'` for characters, e.g. `['n','o']` or `"no"`. Also `a ->  …` will always match. You want `'a' -> …`.

Comment: Look, I love that more people are getting into Haskell, and I'm trying to be gentle here, but perhaps learning Haskell on your own shouldn't be your first introduction to a programming language? Maybe you could try a nice "intro to programming" Coursera course instead. (I've heard great things about them)

Comment: There have been a few of these questions lately where the answer was, "you have to quote your characters." I wonder whether they're related and where these tutorials or college courses are that are causing confusion.

Comment: @DanielMartin I understand your point, but I don't think there's anything wrong with learning Haskell as a first programming language. Moving from imperative programming to pure FP, one usually has to unlearn certain habits ("how do I modify `x`?"), while learning FP upfront can make it simpler.

Comment: @chi, I see what you're saying but if you're approaching Haskell with so little programming experience that the distinction between quoted literals and variable names is surprising, you shouldn't be attempting to go it all on your own. Find a course or a book or even a step-by-step walk through online. Don't just pick ghci/ghc up and go from zero. (That being said, I still think learning Haskell as a first programming language is not the way to go - I have heard good things about Racket as a first PL though)

Comment: @chi Thing is, most resources I know compare Haskell with imperative languages, like Python or C in their first chapter. I haven't found a resource that teaches Haskell from 0 (yet).

Answer (score 1):

You use the `Char` type wrong, literals are written `'n'`,`'o'`.

You are correct that `String` is just an alias for `[Char]`, so `"no"` is an abbreviation for `['n','o']`.